# Getting a null pointer error..Attempt to de-reference a null object

Tags: apex, visualforce

My vf page:

```
<apex:page controller="NewContact1">
<APEX:form >
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:pageBlockSection >

<apex:inputField value="{!objContact.Firstname}"/>

<apex:inputField value="{!objContact.LastName}" required="false"/>
<apex:inputField value="{!objContact.title}"/>
<apex:inputField value="{!objContact.MobilePhone }"/>
<apex:inputField value="{!objContact.email}"/>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
<apex:pageBlockButtons >
<apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!Savecontact}"/>
<apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/>
</apex:pageBlockButtons>
</apex:pageBlock>
</APEX:form>
</apex:page>
```

My controller :

```
public class NewContact1 
{

    Public Contact objContact{get;set;}
    PUBLIC string recid{get;set;}
    public NewContact1() 
    {    

    }

    public Newcontact1(Apexpages.standardController controller)
    {
        recId = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id');
        this.objContact=(contact)controller.getrecord();
        //objContact.put(objContact.accountid,recid);
       objContact.accountid = recid;
    }


      Public pagereference Savecontact()
    {
        Insert objContact;
        Pagereference Savecontact= new Pagereference('/apex/accountdisplay');
        Savecontact.setredirect(true);
        return Savecontact;

    }

     Public pagereference Cancel()
    {

        Pagereference Cancel= new Pagereference('/apex/accountdisplay');
        Cancel.setredirect(true);
        return Cancel;

    }

}
```

getting the error at Insert objcontact..tried debugging to..it says that the object is null..can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to change the first line of your VF page to:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="NewContact1">
```

Edit: Didn't read your code properly. It also looks like you are trying to pass an Account ID using the ID parameter. This won't work properly because the getRecord() method will use this ID to try and get a contact.

So better to pass an Account ID using a differently named parameter and call your page using something like.

```
/apex/PageName?Id=<ContactID>&accId=<AccountId>
```

And change the first line of the contstructor to

```
recId = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('accIdd');
```

Comment: then the id that i am passsing show an error ...recid variable is account id  .and it displays an error saying invalid ID for standard contact controller

Comment: Yes sorry I missed that, see my edit :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Carl. However, if you do want to use this as the only controller and not an extension, what you would want to do is assign a value to objContact in your first constructor:

```
public NewContact1() 
{    
    objContact = 
}
```